# Error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' when instantiated class of method

Tags: c#, nunit

I have created two projects in MS Visual C# 2010 Express. The first project has a class SugarcrmLogin with the method TheSugarCrmLoginTest().

The second project has a class Sugarcrm with the method Main. This project has a reference to the project dll of the first project.

In the method Main I have instantiated the class SugarcrmLogin and called the SugarCrmLoginTest() method.

Here the code of the Main method in the second project, where I instantiate the class and call the method:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    SugarcrmLogin Login; 
    Login = new SugarcrmLogin(); 
    Login.TheSugarcrmLoginTest();
}
```

Both projects build succesfully in MS Visual C#, but when I try to run the project dll of the second project with Nunit, I get the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' with a reference to TheSugarCrmLoginTest() method in the first project.

### First project

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SugarcrmLogin
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1/";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheSugarcrmLoginTest()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/sugarcrm/index.php?module=Users&action=Login");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_name")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_name")).SendKeys("admin");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_password")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_password")).SendKeys("admin");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_button")).Click();
        }
        private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool IsAlertPresent()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText()
        {
            try
            {
                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                string alertText = alert.Text;
                if (acceptNextAlert)
                {
                    alert.Accept();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert.Dismiss();
                }
                return alertText;
            }
            finally
            {
                acceptNextAlert = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Second project:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Sugarcrm
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        public string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        [SetUp]

        public void SetupTest()
        {
            //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1/";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        public static void Main()
            {
                SugarcrmLogin Login;
                Login = new SugarcrmLogin();
                Login.TheSugarcrmLoginTest();
            }

        private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool IsAlertPresent()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText()
        {
            try
            {
                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                string alertText = alert.Text;
                if (acceptNextAlert)
                {
                    alert.Accept();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert.Dismiss();
                }
                return alertText;
            }
            finally
            {
                acceptNextAlert = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can put a breakpoint and check whether Login variable is null after being initiated

Comment: it sounds most likely that the error is being raised *inside* `TheSugarcrmLoginTest()`, in which case without the code (update: now provided in an edit) we can't even hope to tell you what; but: what is the stack-trace?

Comment: @YuliamChandra while there *is* a way of making `new SomeClass()` return `null`, it is an **extreme** edge case (the only times I've **ever** seen it are in extreme crazy coding examples)

Answer (score 0):

With the edit that shows the code: `driver` is `null`. The constructor does not assign it, and you do not call the  `SetupTest()` method which *does*.

Frankly, though, your `Sugarcrm` unit test shouldn't be instantiating and calling-into another (`SugarcrmLogin`) unit test like that, IMO. This seems like "using your unit test framework incorrectly".

Comment: I'm now calling the SetupTest() and TeardownTest() methods as well, but I still getting the error. Here the code:         public static void Main()
            {
                SugarcrmLogin Setup;
                Setup = new SugarcrmLogin();
                Setup.SetupTest();

                SugarcrmLogin Login;
                Login = new SugarcrmLogin();
                Login.TheSugarcrmLoginTest();

                SugarcrmLogin Teardown;
                Teardown = new SugarcrmLogin();
                Teardown.TeardownTest();
            }

Comment: @user3748074 yes, but **where** are you getting the error? use the debugger, Luke!

Comment: When I try to use the debugger I get the error 'A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly......'. Is there a way to get the debugger working with a class library? I'm using MS Visual C# 2010 Express

Comment: Hi Obi Wan (Marc;-)), what I'm trying to achieve is to execute a a series of tests from Nunit. With Selenium IDE I can execute a series of test (e.g. login, create something, delete something, logout) where the browser doesn't open and close in between each test. In Nunit after each test the browser closes again, as a result the test execution fails (e.g. logout fails because I'm no longer logged in). I would like to have a program that does one setup, calls all test methods and executes them, and then does a teardown. Do you have any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: @user3748074 no, not my area I'm afraid

Comment: Hi Marc, I have been able to find a solution. Instead of creating a project for each test case, I now create one project and add a class for each test case to this project. I have a 'Helper class' in the project containing mehtods for generic actions like login, delete. If for a certain test case I need to make use of one or more generic actions, I instantiate the Helper class in the test case class and call the method that I need. Thanks anyway for your help. The issue can be closed